# Xkb configuration for emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard, x11

I'm trying to remap three keys, left alt, right win and menu, to specific keys for emacs.
Specifically, I wants to use RWIN as Hyper, my left alt as Meta and My MENU as Alt.

I setup xkb in this way. there are two files, the first one is super_hyper (in ~/.xkb/symbols):

```
partial modifier_keys
xkb_symbols "standard" {
    key <LALT> { [ Meta_L, Meta_L ] };
    replace key <RWIN>  { [ Hyper_R, Hyper_R ] };
    replace key <MENU>  { [ Alt_R, Alt_R ] };
    modifier_map Mod1 { <META>, Meta_L };
    modifier_map Mod3 { <HYPR>, Hyper_R };
    modifier_map none { <ALT>, Alt_R };
};
```

the second file (~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd) is really simple:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+it+inet(evdev)+compose(paus)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)+super_hyper(standard)"};
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};
```

Then I setup all with

```
xkbcomp -I$HOME/.xkb ~/.xkb/keymap/mykbd $DISPLAY
```

xev shows that all works perfectly. And emacs works well with the hyper (right windows key) and meta (left alt key) modifiers. But when I use the menu key it responds like a meta modifier, like the alt key. How can I solve?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this link can give you more insight : http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html

Comment: Thank you, but that link doesn't give any way to configure the keyboard other than the gnome/ubuntu GUI (that I suspect will give the xkb options configuration, that are very far to give me what I want).
And I don't need a way to remap normal keys, I already can do that, I can have super and hyper easily. What I really need is to have an Alt key that is recognized by emacs as an Alt key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your left `alt` key should already be mapped as a `meta` key. I will show you on an example how to configure Emacs to recognize the `AltGr` (right alt) as a `hyper` key. You can adapt the example then to your needs.

1. Find out the key code of the `AltGr` key:

Run in a console: `xev`. Hit afterwards repeatedly the `AltGr` key and close then the program. In the output, you can read the key code for `AltGr`. I get:

```
...keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R)...
```

2. Next, we check how our keys are bound with the following command: xmodmap -pm. In my case, I get:

```bash
shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3
mod4
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

In hexadecimal, the keycode 108 (hex 0x6c) is associated with `Alt_R`.

3. Remove `Alt_R` from `mod1` as we want to map it to `hyper`. This step is optional. For example, my `menu` key (hex code: 0x87) does not appear in this output. Therefore I can skip this step.

```bash
# remove all keys associated to mod1
xmodmap -e "clear mod1"
# but as we are only interested in Alt_R, re-assign those we removed wrongly
xmodmap -e "add mod1 = Alt_L Meta_L"
```

4. Now, we can re-assign `AltGr` key to `Hyper` (you can choose other keys such as: `Alt_R` or `Super_L`, `Super_H`, ...:

```bash
xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = Hyper_R"
```

5. Finally, the next step consists in assigning this key symbol to a modifier. I chose mod3 (mainly because it is empty):

```bash
xmodmap -e "add mod3 = Hyper_R"
```

6. In Emacs, when I hit now `AltGr-f`, it tells me that `H-f` is undefined. I can go now and use the hyper key for new keybindings:

```bash
(global-set-key (kbd "H-f") 'find-file)
```

If I had chosen in step 4-5 to assign `AltGr` and `mod3` to `Super_R`, I would have used `"S-f"` for the new keybinding in step 6. Similarly, assigning `AltGr` to `Alt_R` in step 4-5 would have resulted in using e.g. `"A-f"` when setting the binding.

**EDIT**

If you want to assign a key (e.g. `menu` key) to  `Alt_R`, one has to make sure that the `Meta_L` key is mapped (e.g. to `mod1`). If `Meta_L` (e.g. assigned to `Alt_L`) does not appear in your `xmodmap -pm` output, then very likely, your key (e.g. `menu`) acts as a further `meta` modifier.

Comment: I have not problems to set keys, and I don't need to remap alt key (that's meta). I  only wants a key (menu) to be mapped as alt (not meta). And already I do that, xev shows that works well, but for strange reasons (maybe the emacs alt to meta fallback? Or some mod mapping wrong?) emacs don't recognize that as alt, but as meta. I want to know why and how to solve.

Comment: How can you bind the alt key in Emacs ? Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't meta on old keyboards what is today the alt key ?

Comment: Emacs is capable to have different keybindings with alt and meta, so I'd have another modifier different by meta: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifier-Keys.html
And yes, the alt key normally sends meta. And I have that same behaviour with my keyboard. But I want to have an additional modifier.

Comment: You see this in my answer if I am not mistaking. I give an example on how to assign right Alt key to Hyper. However, in the last paragraph I mention how to make the right Alt behave like an actual Alt key. In your case, you need to get the menu keycode, remove to whatever it is bound e.g. mod1 (optional), repeat step 4 but instead of Hyper_R, you should use Alt_R and finally map it to mod3 (step 5). Then, it will behave like an Alt.  I gave an example of the right Alt key mainly for illustration.

Comment: I slightly modified the last paragraph.

Comment: I updated the answer (after EDIT) now showing how to map a key to Alt. If it doesn't work out for you, can you show me you `xmodmap -pm` output.

Comment: Ok, I think we are very near to the solution. The very thing I missed in my earlier configuration (very similar to yours, but made with xkb) was the fact that Alt_R must be in a mod. But when I put it in a mod with other modifier keys it works like a meta. It have to be an empty one! But I don't have any free mod, so now I have to figure out how to solve in my personal configuration!